# Embed microsoft expression blend inside a .net application

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml, blend

Is there any way to embed microsoft expression blend inside a .net application ( to create xaml files)?
If not is there any other xaml designer to use instead?

More detail: I want to let end user, to design UI by xaml designer at runtime.

Comment: No, they would have to obtain a licensed copy of Expression Blend to use it.  There's no reason to embed an entire application inside another application like this.  You can, however, write a custom XAML editor yourself.  There's one called XAML Cruncher that is part of the source code for a book, you can download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/mspress/companion/0-7356-1957-3) if this is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

```
To design
```

1. Open an Project in visual studio.
2. In solution explorer right click on your .xaml file.
3. Click open with.
4. Select expression blend.
5. Design xaml file
6. Save it
7. Your .xaml file inside .net project in visual studio will automatically be updated with each save.

> You can also create .xaml file in expression blend and then add the
>   xaml file into your .net application.

1. Right click on your application name in solution explorer in visual studio.
2. click add
3. click existing item

Comment: sorry, i think there is some misunderestanding about my question. i mean i want to let end user to create xaml files at run time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to give your users a XAML editor for editing XAML with Visual studio functionality, then you may have to learn about Embeding Visual Studio Editor in your application. Something like this:
http://dotneteers.net/blogs/divedeeper/archive/2010/07/28/LearnVSXNow_2D00_Part45.aspx

Moreover, you can also distribute this, but you will have to find details about its Licensing issues. I heard that Microsoft allows it for free, but not sure.